# How to add openssl dependency to gemspec?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

It's a relatively common error for new users of Ruby on Linux to not have openssl compiled into their Ruby.   We've got a gem that requires 'openssl' and every once in a while it blows up on somebody with a LoadError on 'openssl'.   The fix is usually to point them at 
https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/

Is there any way to convert this from a run-time error into an install error?   We can't add a dependency in the gemspec because openssl isn't a gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking for the lib by putting some code in mkrf_conf.rb

Take a look at https://github.com/timcharper/spork/blob/master/ext/mkrf_conf.rb where the author checks for the OS and installes a gem. I am sure you can check for the OS and install a package (ie: apt-get install openssl-lib in ubuntu ...etc).

Another [example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems).

Never tried this my self though. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: works a charm:  https://github.com/tablatom/hobo/commit/0085d4d3c5fdf2f71ca8f4412927c5147fa3d96f